# To create Categorical Heatmaps in Qgis do I need 1 heatmap or 1 per layer for each category

Tags: qgis, heat-map, multi-band

In Qgis 2.18 I have a points layer and can create a raster heatmap for all the points with singleband pseudocolour. If I wanted to show separate categories as different colour ramps do I need to create 1 raster per category and manually select a different colour or is there a smarter way to accomplish the same thing and is it correct to call that a multi-band heatmap?